# WebLogic Config.bat Not Open

Tags: weblogic

the config screen turns on and off when I click config.bat in the extension below. What might be the source of the problem?

I have added JAVA_HOME to the environment variables and am I supposed to add something else?

```
C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin
```

Microsoft Windows [Sürüm 6.1.7601]
Telif Hakkı (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Tüm hakları saklıdır.

C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin

```
C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin>config.bat
'config.bat' iç ya da dış komut, çalıştırılabilir
program ya da toplu iş dosyası olarak tanınmıyor.

C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin>config

C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin>/@ECHO OFF
'/@ECHO' iç ya da dış komut, çalıştırılabilir
program ya da toplu iş dosyası olarak tanınmıyor.

C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin>SETLOCAL

C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin>FOR /F %i in ('cd') do
 set MYPWD=%i

C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin>set MYPWD=C:\Oracle\Mi
ddleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin

C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin>SET SCRIPT_PATH=C:\Ora
cle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin\

C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin>FOR %i IN ("C:\Oracle\
Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin\") DO SET SCRIPT_PATH=%~fsi

C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin>SET SCRIPT_PATH=C:\Ora
cle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\bin\

C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin>FOR %i IN ("C:\Oracle\
MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\bin\\..\..") DO SET ORACLE_HOME=%~fsi

C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin>SET ORACLE_HOME=C:\Ora
cle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\ORACLE~1

C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin>FOR %i IN ("C:\Oracle\
MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\ORACLE~1\..") DO SET MW_HOME=%~fsi

C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin>SET MW_HOME=C:\Oracle\
MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1

C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin>CALL "C:\Oracle\MIDDLE
~1\ORACLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\bin\\setHomeDirs.cmd"

C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin>^A
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: For *.bat, you can add a `pause` at the end of the file to see if there are any errors. Alternately you can use CMD/Powershell and run the file config.bat on prompt.

Comment: I added a picture. In this way, the screen turns on and then turns off. There is no error on the screen @RajeevSreedharan

Comment: I added cmd output @RajeevSreedharan

Comment: What's the OS, Weblogic version and Java version you are using?

Comment: Java jdk1.8.0_131 , WebLogic 12.2.1.2.0 , Windows 7 x64 @RajeevSreedharan

Comment: Icons do not appear on the start menu. I guess I'm missing something